# Trying to cross-compile QtWebEngine for ARM7

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, cross-compiling, arm7

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04, on an AMD64 CPU.
I'm trying to cross-compile the Qt5.7.1 code, including the QtWebEngine, for ARM7.

I've managed to successfully compile the Qt library natively for AMD64, and have also managed to compile QtCore to make a basic Qt application that runs on my ARM7 target.

My problem comes with trying to cross-compile the QtWebEngine component, which requires OpenGLES2. I'm attempting to configure the cross-compile as such:

```
../qt5/configure -release -opengl es2 -device linux-beaglebone-g++ -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=/home/doug/workspace/gcc-linaro-4.9-2016.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf- -nomake tools -nomake examples -opensource -confirm-license -prefix /opt/Qt5.7.1_ARM7 -v -pkg-config
```

Here is the Beaglebone qmake file referenced:

```
#
# qmake configuration for the BeagleBoard and BeagleBoard xM boards
# http://beagleboard.org/

MAKEFILE_GENERATOR      = UNIX
CONFIG                 += incremental
QMAKE_INCREMENTAL_STYLE = sublib

include(../../common/linux.conf)
include(../../common/gcc-base-unix.conf)
include(../../common/g++-unix.conf)

load(device_config)

QT_QPA_DEFAULT_PLATFORM = eglfs

# modifications to g++.conf
QMAKE_CC                = $${CROSS_COMPILE}gcc
QMAKE_CXX               = $${CROSS_COMPILE}g++
QMAKE_LINK              = $${QMAKE_CXX}
QMAKE_LINK_SHLIB        = $${QMAKE_CXX}

# modifications to linux.conf
QMAKE_AR                = $${CROSS_COMPILE}ar cqs
QMAKE_OBJCOPY           = $${CROSS_COMPILE}objcopy
QMAKE_NM                = $${CROSS_COMPILE}nm -P
QMAKE_STRIP             = $${CROSS_COMPILE}strip

COMPILER_FLAGS          = -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a8 -mfpu=neon -mthumb -mfloat-abi=hard

#modifications to gcc-base.conf
QMAKE_CFLAGS           += $${COMPILER_FLAGS}
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS         += $${COMPILER_FLAGS}
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += -O3

QMAKE_LIBS             += -lrt -lpthread -ldl

# Extra stuff (OpenGL, DirectFB, ...)
QMAKE_INCDIR_EGL        = /home/doug/build/Wayland/install/include
QMAKE_LIBDIR_EGL        = /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
QMAKE_INCDIR_OPENGL_ES2 = $${QMAKE_INCDIR_EGL}
QMAKE_LIBDIR_OPENGL_ES2 = $${QMAKE_LIBDIR_EGL}
QMAKE_INCDIR_OPENVG     = $${QMAKE_INCDIR_EGL}
QMAKE_LIBDIR_OPENVG     = $${QMAKE_LIBDIR_EGL}

QMAKE_LIBS_EGL          = -lEGL
QMAKE_LIBS_OPENGL_ES2   = -lGLESv2 $${QMAKE_LIBS_EGL}
QMAKE_LIBS_OPENVG       = -lOpenVG $${QMAKE_LIBS_EGL}

DISTRO_OPTS += hard-float

# No need for any special EGL device integration.
# Prioritize the default, compiled-in integration over any plugins.
EGLFS_DEVICE_INTEGRATION = none

include(../common/linux_arm_device_post.conf)

load(qt_config)
```

I have enabled multi-arch on my Ubuntu install and have installed the armhf version of the libgles2-dev package, which the cross-compiler seems happy with.

The problem now is that the compiler doesn't seem to be able to see additional libraries that opengles2 depends on - here's what I'm currently getting:

```
checking for OpenGL ES 2.0... 
/home/doug/workspace/gcc-linaro-4.9-2016.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -c -pipe -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a8 -mfpu=neon -mthumb -mfloat-abi=hard -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a8 -mfpu=neon -mthumb -mfloat-abi=hard -mfloat-abi=hard -O2 -O3 -Wall -W -fPIC  -I/home/doug/workspace/qt5/qtbase/config.tests/unix/opengles2 -I. -I/home/doug/build/Wayland/install/include -I/home/doug/workspace/qt5/qtbase/mkspecs/devices/linux-beaglebone-g++ -o opengles2.o /home/doug/workspace/qt5/qtbase/config.tests/unix/opengles2/opengles2.cpp
/home/doug/workspace/gcc-linaro-4.9-2016.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -mfloat-abi=hard -Wl,-O1 -o opengles2 opengles2.o   -lrt -lpthread -ldl -L/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -lGLESv2 -lEGL 
/home/doug/workspace/gcc-linaro-4.9-2016.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9.4/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: warning: libglapi.so.0, needed by /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libGLESv2.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/doug/workspace/gcc-linaro-4.9-2016.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9.4/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: warning: libX11-xcb.so.1, needed by /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/doug/workspace/gcc-linaro-4.9-2016.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9.4/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: warning: libxcb-dri2.so.0, needed by /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/doug/workspace/gcc-linaro-4.9-2016.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9.4/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: warning: libxcb-dri3.so.0, needed by /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/doug/workspace/gcc-linaro-4.9-2016.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9.4/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: warning: libxcb-present.so.0, needed by /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/doug/workspace/gcc-linaro-4.9-2016.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9.4/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: warning: libxcb-xfixes.so.0, needed by /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/doug/workspace/gcc-linaro-4.9-2016.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9.4/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: warning: libxcb-sync.so.1, needed by /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/doug/workspace/gcc-linaro-4.9-2016.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9.4/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: warning: libxcb.so.1, needed by /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/doug/workspace/gcc-linaro-4.9-2016.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9.4/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: warning: libxshmfence.so.1, needed by /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/doug/workspace/gcc-linaro-4.9-2016.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9.4/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: warning: libwayland-client.so.0, needed by /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/doug/workspace/gcc-linaro-4.9-2016.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9.4/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: warning: libwayland-server.so.0, needed by /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/doug/workspace/gcc-linaro-4.9-2016.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9.4/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: warning: libgbm.so.1, needed by /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/doug/workspace/gcc-linaro-4.9-2016.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9.4/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: warning: libexpat.so.1, needed by /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/doug/workspace/gcc-linaro-4.9-2016.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9.4/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: warning: libdrm.so.2, needed by /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `wl_display_dispatch_pending'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_dri3_open_reply'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_xfixes_destroy_region'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `drmIoctl'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_dri2_get_buffers_reply'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `wl_proxy_add_listener'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `wl_client_post_no_memory'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `XGetXCBConnection'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_connection_has_error'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_present_query_capabilities'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_dri2_get_buffers_with_format_reply'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_dri2_connect_driver_name'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_depth_visuals_length'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `drmGetCap'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `wl_proxy_destroy'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `XML_ParserCreate'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_unregister_for_special_event'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `drmGetMagic'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_create_pixmap'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `gbm_bo_import'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `wl_display_disconnect'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_dri2_query_version'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_dri2_connect_reply'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `wl_resource_post_error'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_dri2_authenticate_unchecked'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `wl_resource_destroy'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_dri2_copy_region_reply'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_get_extension_data'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `drmFreeVersion'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_dri2_swap_buffers_unchecked'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `XML_GetErrorCode'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_free_gc'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `XML_SetUserData'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xshmfence_map_shm'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `wl_resource_get_user_data'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_get_image_reply'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_put_image'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `wl_event_queue_destroy'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `wl_buffer_interface'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_copy_area'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_dri2_connect_device_name_length'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_get_image_data_length'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_xfixes_query_version'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_present_query_capabilities_reply'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `wl_proxy_set_queue'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_get_image_data'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `XML_GetCurrentColumnNumber'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_connect'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_prefetch_extension_data'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_dri3_id'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_present_select_input_checked'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_setup_roots_iterator'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_dri3_pixmap_from_buffer'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_present_query_version'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_dri3_open_reply_fds'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_dri2_get_buffers_with_format_buffers'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `wl_resource_set_implementation'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `wl_resource_instance_of'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_dri2_connect_driver_name_length'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_dri3_query_version_reply'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_dri2_get_msc'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_get_setup'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_copy_area_checked'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_present_id'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_poll_for_special_event'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `XML_ParseBuffer'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_dri2_swap_interval'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_get_geometry'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_dri2_create_drawable_checked'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_depth_visuals'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `wl_resource_create'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `gbm_device_get_fd'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_dri2_destroy_drawable'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_dri2_connect_device_name'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_flush'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `wl_display_interface'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_get_geometry_reply'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `XML_GetCurrentLineNumber'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `wl_shm_pool_interface'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `wl_global_destroy'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xshmfence_unmap_shm'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `wl_callback_interface'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_dri2_id'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xshmfence_reset'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `wl_global_create'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `drmCommandWriteRead'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `wl_shm_interface'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_present_pixmap'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `wl_display_connect'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `wl_registry_interface'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_xfixes_id'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `wl_proxy_marshal'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_dri3_buffer_from_pixmap_reply_fds'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_register_for_special_xge'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_dri2_copy_region_unchecked'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_screen_allowed_depths_iterator'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xshmfence_alloc_shm'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `XML_ErrorString'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `gbm_device_get_backend_name'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xshmfence_await'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_dri2_swap_buffers_reply'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_sync_destroy_fence'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_get_image'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `gbm_create_device'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_dri2_authenticate_reply'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `wl_display_dispatch_queue'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_xfixes_query_version_reply'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `wl_display_flush'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_dri2_get_buffers_unchecked'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_dri3_open'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_xfixes_create_region'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `gbm_device_destroy'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `XML_ParserFree'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_present_query_version_reply'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `wl_resource_post_no_memory'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_create_gc'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_dri2_get_msc_reply'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_free_pixmap'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_discard_reply'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `XML_SetElementHandler'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `drmGetVersion'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `wl_proxy_marshal_constructor'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_dri3_buffer_from_pixmap_reply'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `XML_Parse'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_dri3_fence_from_fd'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `XML_GetBuffer'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_sync_trigger_fence'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_request_check'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_generate_id'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_dri2_create_drawable'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `gbm_bo_create'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_screen_next'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_disconnect'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_dri2_connect_unchecked'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `wl_resource_post_event'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `drmAuthMagic'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xshmfence_trigger'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_dri3_buffer_from_pixmap'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `drmGetRenderDeviceNameFromFd'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_wait_for_special_event'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_dri3_query_version'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `wl_display_create_queue'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_dri2_get_buffers_with_format_unchecked'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `drmGetNodeTypeFromFd'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_dri2_query_version_reply'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `gbm_bo_destroy'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_depth_next'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_present_notify_msc'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libGLESv2.so: undefined reference to `_glapi_tls_Dispatch'
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so: undefined reference to `xcb_dri2_get_buffers_buffers'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:91: recipe for target 'opengles2' failed
```

Doe anyone have any insight as to what I need to do to proceed? Do I need to install armhf versions of all of these libraries?

Thanks, and greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pollute your Ubuntu installation with ARM packages. The configuration script for Qt allows [passing `sysroot` as an argument](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2012/04/13/cross-compiling-qt-for-the-masses/). For example when I work with the Raspberry Pi I don't even have to use the SD card. I just mount the filesystems the image file contains (one boot and one with the installation of the actual Linux distro (Raspbian etc.)) and use that. I haven't worked with a Beaglebone yet but from what I understand you can have a running Linux installation on it so using the already provided libraries from that installation will allow you a nice way to handle all the dependencies that the building process requires. If some libraries are missing you can install these on your running ARM Linux installation. Omho that's the easier way to do it since you can simply use the package manager of that ARM distro to download and install the missing libraries.